# Unresponsive localhost

Tags: codeigniter, wamp, virtualhost

I have set up wamp 2.5 in my windows 7 (32 bit). I have set up a virtual host `accounting.dev` and set up the hosts file 
`127.0.0.1  localhost
127.0.0.1 accounting.dev` 
When I try to access localhost `http://localhost` The page keeps spinning and loads after a very long long time. When the localhost loads I see that the my it is trying to connect this IP address 192.168.0.4. When the page loads I see `connected to 192.168.0.4` at the bottom left corner of the browser(firefox). Finally when the page loads my page do not show any of the styles that is applied to it (I use codeigniter). When trying to access the page from the virtualhost `http://accounting.dev) the page loads as usual.
Here is my virtual host configuration.

```
     <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
     ServerName localhost
     ServerAlias localhost
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost *:80>
     DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/accounting"
     ServerName accounting.dev
     <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/accounting">
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Is there anything wrong with my virtual host setup. Why does the page look for 192.168.0.4 and my IPv4 address is `192.168.3.50`. The laptop(one having the problem) is connected to WiFi, and the WiFi is broadcasted from another laptop (IP address 172.16.14.193) and I use connectify hostspot as the virtual router to share wifi in my house. Agai when I disable WiFi of my system, localhost serves the pages as usual(fast) but without all those styles and javascripts! Please help me on this, Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that the `DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"` in your virtualhost config is the correct path to your page? Also check that the path to your css in the source is correct?

Comment: Oh I forgot to change the base url to "http://localhost". This was the problem. Now i get to see the page with styles and the page loads fast as well.

Comment: Now the only problem is when i click the login page it shows me a blank page

Comment: Then you may have a PHP error. Turn on error reporting in index.php. `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @JimboSlice `if (defined('ENVIRONMENT'))
{
 switch (ENVIRONMENT)
 {
  case 'development':
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
  break;
 
  case 'testing':
  case 'production':
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
  break;

  default:
   exit('The application environment is not set correctly.');
 }
}` I have changed it dont see anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i followed a tutorial , i don't remember its link but here is the changes you need to setup your localhost with virtual server name just open httpd.conf file and add following lines and make sure wamp is in c:\wamp

```
<VirtualHost localhost>    
    DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/   
    ServerName localhost    
</VirtualHost>  

<VirtualHost accounting.dev>    
   DocumentRoot c:/wamp/www/accounting/ 
   ServerName accounting.dev   
</VirtualHost>
```

i hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks @imran qasim, my virtual host setting works. It displays the index page but not the pages after that

Comment: as you have mentioned tag codeigniter so are you using codeigniter with your project if yest than check what settings you have in $base_url of you config.php file in config folder. because i am also using codeigniter and with same configuration which i have posted and i have no problem navigating to pages.

Comment: Thanks @imran your settings works both in Xampp as well as wamp. But in wamp i cant proceed after login page, in xampp i can successfully view all the pages. in wamp i get 404 Not found error. What would be the cause...I think it should work in both wamp and xampp

Comment: i left using wamp a long time ago as i was facing something similar problems in my previous task so i prefer to use XAMPP so if this solution is working in XAMPP so i think rather than wasting your time on WAMP its better you use XAMPP , sorry no offence against WAMP but this is how it works.